# Kendo grid drop down not translating numeric values

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have managed to set the options array on a kendo grid column after the grid has been initialised. During initialisation I pass the column in question an empty array then this array is populated with an array of objects after initialisation using JavaScript. The option objects are of the type { value: 1, text: 'text' } with the 'text' begin the displayed value & when selected translated into the corresponding value - 1.

However when the grid is loaded with data the number values are not being translated into their corresponding text values and are being displayed as numbers. Interestingly when you click on a cell of this column type the translation is then performed. How can I get the number value to be translated into its text value when the grid is loaded with data, is there an option setting that I am missing?

```
var optCategory = [];

$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [],
    columns: [ { field: 'Category', title: 'Category', width: '100%', values: optCategory } ],
    editable: true
});

(function getCategoryValues () {
    var grd = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');

    var o = { value: 1, text: 'Option 1' };
    grd.columns[0].values.push(o);

    var o = { value: 2, text: 'Option 2' };
    grd.columns[0].values.push(o);

    var o = { value: 3, text: 'Option 3' };
    grd.columns[0].values.push(o);
})();

var products = [ { Category: 2 } ];

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: products
});

$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(ds);
// $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(); - no effect
// $('#grid').refresh(); - no effect

http://jsfiddle.net/EddyBu/c7kztssq/2/
```

Thank you!

Comment: post the code including mark up....

Comment: Hi Shaz a jsfiddle of my problem can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/EddyBu/c7kztssq/2/. Option 2 should be the displayed value instead of the value 2.